# Extracting text data between two dashed lines without using regex?

Tags: python, parsing

I want to extract data between dashed lines without regular expressions. Example of the input is shown in the following image:

[image: input text]

There are 30k lines like this.

Comment: Making the question a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.takewhile` and `itertools.dropwhile`. I'm assuming only the dashed lines can start with a dash.

```
from itertools import takewhile, dropwhile

file = iter('''---
data1
data2
---
stuff
---
data3
data4
---'''.splitlines())

def in_between(data):
    data = iter(data) # make sure data is iterator
    not_dashed = lambda line: not line.startswith('-')

    while True:
        data = dropwhile(not_dashed, data)
        next(data)
        for x in takewhile(not_dashed, data):
            yield x
        next(data)

for x in in_between(file):
    print x
```

Output:

```
data1
data2
data3
data4
```

Since this solution never reads the whole file into memory but works with iterators and one line at a time, you should have no problems processing very large files.